# Python: Fast subsetting of pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large pandas dataframe with ~500k lines and 40columns.

```
>>> data 
       ColA  ColB     ColC           ...          ColX     ColY  ColZ
445828   A     10     2020-02-21     ...             6      nan  2019-08-13
445829   B     12     2020-02-21     ...             8      nan  2019-08-13
445830   C     13     2020-02-21     ...            10      nan  2019-08-13
445831   D     15     2020-02-21     ...            12      nan  2019-08-13
445832   E     17     2020-02-21     ...            15      nan  2019-08-13
```

I use this dataframe inside a class. One of the method of this class is `get_property(self, A, B, C)`.

```
def get_property(self, option_basics):
    data_subset = self.data[(self.data.colA == A) &
                       (self.data.colB == B) &
                       (self.data.colC == C)]
    return data_subset
```

I make this query hundreds of time. It's relatively time consuming. Is there a way to increase the speed of this request?

I have already used `data.set_index(['colA', 'colB', 'colC'])`

Comment: Since you set the index, if the index is unique you'll get a big performance improvement with `df.loc[(A,B,C)]` to return the Series. Otherwise you still get faster selection with `loc` but a `PerformanceWarning`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the index massively improved the performance of the query (keeping the columns used in the dataframe for backward compatibility)

> data.set_index(['colA', 'colB', 'colC'], **drop = False**)
>
> df.loc[A,B,C]